# How to change the default output of \ref

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, footmisc, bigfoot

Here is a minimal example of my work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,openbib]{book} 
\usepackage[total={5in, 8in}]{geometry} 
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[ruled]{bigfoot}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcounter{footalt}
\def\thefootalt{\fnsymbol{footalt}}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}  
\renewcommand {\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnote}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{C}[roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{D}[Alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{E}[Roman]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{F}[fnsymbol]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteC}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteD}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteE}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteF}

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{5mm}
\usepackage{endnotes,chngcntr}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\makeatletter         %<-- these lines add the page numbering
\long\def\@endnotetext#1{%
    \if@enotesopen \else \@openenotes \fi
    \immediate\write\@enotes{\@doanenote{\ [pg \thepage] \@theenmark}}
    %\immediate\write\@enotes{\@doanenote{\@theenmark}}
    \begingroup
    \def\next{#1}
    \newlinechar='40
    \immediate\write\@enotes{\meaning\next}%
    \endgroup
    \immediate\write\@enotes{\@endanenote}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\notesname}{Footnotes of Chapter \thechapter} %<-- this is for the title of the footnotes at the end of the chapter
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter} %<-- this restarts the numbering of the footnotes for each chapter, requires the package "chngcntr"
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

    \mainmatter
    \part{part 1}
    \chapter{chapter 1}

    Testing FFFF\footnote{\label{001}footnote 1 ootnote 1\footnoteB{footnote 2\footnoteC{footnote 3\footnoteD{footnote 4 footnote 4 footnote 4 footnote 4 } footnote 3 footnote 3 footnote 3 } footnote 2 footnote 2 } footnote 1 ootnote 1 ootnote 1 } Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing ``Cf. \ref{001}" Testing 
\newpage
\begingroup
\parindent 0pt
\parskip 2ex
\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\theendnotes %<---- this prints all the footnotes together
\endgroup


\end{document}
```

In this work, I added `[pg \thepage]` to make a new form of footnote mark for my footnote per chapter and got the result as follows:

[image]

However, since then, when I use \ref to the label to a footnote, the information added appearing corresponsively. It shows as follows:

[image]

Is there any way I can ignore the new information I added when I use \ref?